# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.' Exception under iOS

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, maui

I am using Entity Framework Core v7.0.14 in .NET MAUI.

On Android with Android Emulator, I can run my app successfully and work and use the database. But, on **iOS** I get an exception at line

```
Database.Migrate();
```

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'

The path in `DatabaseConstants.DatabasePath` is `/Users/mauioxo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/07111E00-92FE-4C7B-8809-9AA8549ABDF6/data/Containers/Data/Application/6E9670A6-76A0-4333-8A8E-4BF44F3C97C8/Documents/../Library/StudentsDatabaseSQLite.db3` and gets determined with the following method:

```cs
public static string GetDatabasePath()
{
    var databasePath = "";
    var databaseName = "StudentsDatabaseSQLite.db3";

    if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, databaseName);
    }
    else if (DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
    {
        SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

        databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library");

        // Make sure the Directory exists otherwise create it
        if (!Directory.Exists(databasePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(databasePath);
        }

        databasePath = Path.Combine(databasePath, databaseName);
    }

    return databasePath;
}
```

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comment out this method for "dotnet ef migrations add <...>" command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="options"></param>
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            // Use $"Data Source={""} ..." for "dotnet ef migrations add <...>" command
            //string connectionString = $"Data Source={DatabaseConstants.DatabasePath};Mode=ReadWriteCreate";
            string connectionString = $"Filename={DatabaseConstants.DatabasePath}";

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
            optionsBuilder.EnableDetailedErrors(true);

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the code in `GetDatabasePath()` as I looked for a solution to the error on the internet and found some hints that the path to the database file could not be created. So, I used the code to make sure the directory exists, otherwise it would create it.

But, to be honest the `Directory.CreateDirectory(databasePath);` was never reached and obviously the parent directory to my database file is available.

How could I load my SQLite database file with Entity Framework Core on iOS?

==== **Update to get the DatabasePath** ====

I tried to use the GetDatabasePath() methode in hope it helps. Well, strange thing is, when I use this Code in **MauiProgram.cs** to determine my DatabasePath and assign it so that it can be used for my ConntectionString in my DatabaseContext it works. Well, works is a bit too optimistic. I still get Exceptions when my App is starting, but obviously I can use my EF Database afterwards which I couldn't before.

It also does not crash with the mentioned Exception all the time. But, it still happens when I delete my app completely from Emulator and run it again. Then, when running it for the first time I still get the mentioned Exception above, but can access my Database.

When the App is started afterwards, there are still 3 Exceptions when Database.Migrate() is called, but not the one mentioned in this post.

```cs
public static string GetDatabasePath()
{
    var databasePath = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
    
    SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

    // Ensure the directory exists; create it if it doesn't
    if (!Directory.Exists(databasePath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(databasePath);
    }

    return databasePath;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have special logic for the path in iOS?  That should not be necessary.  See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-8.0#configure-app-constants

Comment: That's how I started and was confused why on Android it worked fine and everything working correctly. When I tried it on iOS (without enabling Exceptions Settings while Debugging) it crashed. I was confused why and enabled Exceptions Setting. When I hit these I looked on the internet and saw that it was used like that in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c2u3NzrAO0 Would you always use ```FileSystem.AppDataDirectory```?

Comment: also, why are you calling `SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();` for only iOS?

Comment: Well, this was just because it was done like that in the video above. I tried this approach as in the video it seemed to work well. So, I gave it a try. I am not sure if ```SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();``` is really needed. Would you still use it? I also had some success now, but it doesn't make sense why this made a difference (see Update of my question). I still get Exceptions on startup, but not the one I mentioned. Just the "FileNotFoundException" I had the whole time. But now, I can use my App and deploy to my iPhone. Still would like to know what the initial issue was and the Exceptions

Comment: The Stacktrace at this FileNotFoundException is ```at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName , StackCrawlMark& , AssemblyLoadContext )
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(Assembly , CultureInfo , Version , Boolean )```, the ExceptionSource is ```JWT Payload was not valid JSON.```. The next one is ```Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources```. The next one is an IOException - ```Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.resources```

Comment: @Jason - Do you understand the Exception situation or did also have them while your .NET MAUI App was started? I was thinking if the Database.Migrate() could also do its part. But, I need to do that in some place while the App is started. The idea was to use EF to do the "Version Control" of the Database and it includes the Updates at some point while the App is started